# pycassaShell keybindings arrows don't work ^[[A

Tags: pycassa

When in pycassaShell, If I press arrow keys to move the cursor,
I see ^[[A to ^[[D characters appended,
it doesn't happen with normal python console interpreter

nb:

Python 2.6.5, / Ubuntu 10.04
pycassa installed just now using http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/installation.html
and running first http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py, without it, it complained

I have this warning when running pucassaShell:
[I]: IPython not found, falling back to default interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/assorted/pycassa_shell.html